# Is there a real continuous function that extends the domain of this function?

Tags: functions

Is there a real continuous function that extends the domain of this function?

$$ f(k)
\begin{cases}
if \:k \equiv 1 \:\mod\:2, \quad f(k) = \frac{k+1}{k}\\
\\if \:k \equiv 0 \:\mod\: 2, \quad f(k) = \frac{k-1}{k}
\end{cases}
$$
[Graph of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLww6.png)

Comment: There are billion continuous functions that interpolate given points, where is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

$$f(x)=\frac{x-1}x \cos^2 \left(\frac{\pi}2x\right)+\frac{x+1}x \sin^2 \left(\frac{\pi}2x\right)$$

which can be simplified by trigonometric identities

$$f(x)=1-\frac1x\left[2\cos^2 \left(\frac{\pi}2x\right)-1\right] =1-\frac{\cos \left(\pi x\right)}x$$

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! That's perfect!

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes of course it can be simplified, I've let the full expression to see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

example
$$
f(x) = 1 - {1 \over x}\left( {\cos \pi x} \right)
$$

Comment: Yo Nice Function! Thank you so much for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

$$ f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{when }x=0 \\ 1 - \frac1x\bigl(\cos(\pi x) - \sin(\pi x)/\pi x\bigr) & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$
is continuous (in fact real analytic) on all of $\mathbb R$ and agrees with your original definition at all points where it is defined.